# Need to Fix Fuzzy pixels around CSS3 Loader

Tags: css

I'm making a css3 loader animation and I'm having trouble making it really crisp. Because I'm using two circles essentially, there is a slight bump in the edge because of the two overlaying circles.

Any idea on how to fix this?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdylp

```
<div class="loader loader-2"></div>

<style type="text/css">
body {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  padding-left: 6.25%;
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 12.5% 100px;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  border: 2px solid #0cf;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  animation: spin 4.5s infinite linear;
}
.loader::before,
.loader::after {
  left: -2px;
  top: -2px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  border: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/*
 * LOADER 2
 */
.loader-2 {
  border-top-color: transparent;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
}
.loader-2::after {
  display: block;
  left: -2px;
  top: -2px;
  border: inherit;
  transform: rotate(300deg);
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.stopped {
  animation: spin 1004.5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`transform`s will often make the appearance of an object blurry due to the way the browser manipulates the element. It doesn't look bad in Chrome, but all browsers will render it a little differently.

One way to potentially help the blurriness is to scale up, rotate, then scale back down like so:

```
transform: scale(4) rotate(0deg) scale(0.25);
```

Check out the adjusted demo to see if that's any crisper: http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/yiHts

EDIT:
If the background color is known, then you can just have the psuedo element cover part of the circle which will render a little better: http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/pzFtG

With an SVG, you can mask, but browser support isn't great: http://caniuse.com/#search=mask Here's a walkthrough to see if that might be what you need: http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking

Based on our conversation, the best option may be using `clip` on the psuedo elements with a slight rotation on one: http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/JeBHk

Comment: It's about the same really. Can you see that little bump where the quarter circle and 3/4 circle overlap? Because of that, it seems like the rotation is a hair off. I essentially wish I could run a mask over the inner and outer of the final result to shave off the extra

Comment: Ah yes. If the background color is known, then you can just have the psuedo element "clip" the notch out of the circle which will render a little better: http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/pzFtG

Comment: Another possibility is using `clip`. Combined with `border-top-width: 0` it's actually a pretty nice effect: http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/JeBHk

Comment: Unfortunately the background won't be known... but this is really close. If only we could mask the circle.

Comment: Using `clip` is adventuring away from the effect I'll need, unless it can produce the same edge result as before.

Comment: With an SVG, you can mask, but browser support isn't great: http://caniuse.com/#search=mask Here's a walkthrough to see if that might be what you need: http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking

Comment: This was the closest I could get using `clip` individually on the psuedo elements with a slight rotation on one: http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/JeBHk

Comment: Could you update your answer with both these options and I'll accept it! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Done. Hope that helped!

Comment: actually, it doesn't appear to be working in other locations, for example: http://jsbin.com/AbaNEmO/1/edit and locally.

Comment: It's rendering fine in Chrome and Safari. Firefox is a little off-center. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: Got it working, looks like there was an issue with newest version of chrome not recognizing `transform`.